# Cutting a hole in a mounted mirror

Tags: mirror

I have a large mirror that's glued to the wall so I can't remove it. It already has a 1 gang outlet in it but I'd like to expand it to a 2 gang box. How would I expand the hole on a vertical mirror that also has drywall behind it?

Comment: All I can say is good luck and be prepared to buy another mirror.

Comment: Before you go all cut crazy, can you tell us what you want the two gangs for?

Comment: lol, that's what I'm afraid of @SolarMike

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate the 2 outlets that I have today aren't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a 100mm angle grinder and stick a smooth 100mm diamond wheel on it,
you should be able to plunge cut the slots needed to remove the extra piece of glass

wear a dust mask, ear and eye protection,
go slowly brace against the wall pr mirrior with your elbows  and use both hands to steady grinder keep the blade straight when cutting.

wipe down all surfaces with a damp rag when done.

Comment: I would try and practice on a piece of mirror beforehand. Maybe find one in a thrift shop. Of course the two mirrors could behave differently though

Comment: And I suspect that a smaller tool like a rotatry to (often called a Dremel) would be better for the job. It would be easier to control exactly where to cut and where to end a cut. And I imagine it is less likely to shater the entire mirror with vibrations.

Comment: yeah, but much much slower. vibrations won't shatter the mirror. if the cutting wheel jams that could, but with care than can be avoided.

Comment: I suggest setting up a vacuum with the hose very near your cut to capture the dust, preferable one with a HEPA filter. Also wear protective clothing in the case that the mirror breaks as sharp shards many fall down and hit you

Comment: Don't I also need to frequently douse the cutting site with water to reduce friction/heat?

Comment: Water will cool the blade and suppress dust.  but you don't want damp inside the wall. so it's not an option.  Without water the blade wears out faster but it will still last plenty long enough to cut the three slots needed for this task.

Answer (score 3):

Cutting or drilling a hole in a mirror is something that takes either very specialized tools that are not easily available, or an EXTREME amount of luck. If you have a high speed rotary tool, like a Dremel, and a diamond encrusted bit made for grinding glass, you might get lucky. Do NOT breath the dust that comes off of that.